# Remove Query String from Rootdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know with a simple redirect one (Sub-)Domain or Folder to another i can get rid of a string like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld/? [R=301,L]
```

I know how to get rid of it when it is a simple file too.

But when it comes to the Rootdomain itself (http://domain.tld/?Stringwhatsoever), i am at a loss here. My last try used a modified version of a redirect I used to redirect files and folders around and that worked pretty nicely and also removed the query, but it ended up in a redirection error.

```
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.tld/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

So i have no clue how to get rid of Query Strings at urls without breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/? [NC,R,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/? [NC,R,L]
```

Reference :

-https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: Great, i'll try as soon as possible to fix my site and to see if I get it done. Thank you already now for the help!

Comment: Found the Domain that had the Error and the first Rule seems to have worked like a charm!! (Too late to edit my previous Comment :( )