# Redirecting remaining String

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I could clean up all my redirects on my Domain, but one last one still exists.

example.com/?thtml

Here I habe simply no idea how to get rid of it. The worst part, it is in Search results the first result for several keywords.
The site gets shown correctly, but the search result show me only chinese/japanese symbols instead of the description.

> icon ?????????? - ??????????????? ...
>   example.com/?thtml - Translate this site
>   ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
>   ...

The used .htaccess cose you can see below

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php|jpg|jpeg)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^prodotti http://www.example.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^hosting http://www.example.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^housing http://www.example.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^assistenza http://www.example.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^nomeitalia.net http://www.example.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So there are already some RewiteRules added to redirect old directories and things to the main page, but this last remnant drives me crazy. Maybe one of you guys can tell me how i could get rid of it.

Kind Regards, Caylean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked the same question twice... or at least the answer is the same.

As i checked my previous questions, I saw that I might fix the problem here, with a solution I got in that second question. So either this Question here is to be removed or at least answered the same way too I think.

-https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160747/starkeen had given here -[Remove Query String from Rootdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552598/remove-query-string-from-rootdomain) the two possible solutions, where the first one worked also here perfectly.

Starkeen wrote:
Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/? [NC,R,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/? [NC,R,L]
```

Reference :

-https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString